# Problem calling a macro inside sheet code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck in a weird situation.
I have a worksheet_change macro that on triggering should open a workbook, but there's no way to do it and I can't understand why.
I've tried to move the line of code in a separate macro, within the sheet code as well as in a module: this other macro is correctly called (I'm sure of this as I've put inside a welcome msg), but it doesn't open the workbook; but if I run this other macro (the one in the module) directly, it opens the workbook.
The same happens with the userform that the sheet macro calls: if I open the userform within the sheet macro, the workbook is not opened, but if I run the userform direcly the workbook is opened.
Here the part of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_CHANGE(ByVal Target As Range)
x = 5
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S5:S500")) Is Nothing Then
 C = Target.Column:  r = Target.Row
        If Cells(r, C) = "SI" Then
            Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Me\Documents\RATEAZIONEPROVA.xlsm"
            UserForm1.Show
            ' rest of code
```

This is part of code of the userform if workbooks.open is moved into it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 1 To 3
 If Me.Controls("COMBOBOX" & i) = "" Then
    MsgBox "COMPILARE TUTTI I CAMPI PER PROSEGUIRE", vbExclamation, "ERRORE"
    Exit Sub
 End If
Next
For i = 1 To 4
 If Me.Controls("TEXTBOX" & i) = "" Then
    MsgBox "COMPILARE TUTTI I CAMPI PER PROSEGUIRE", vbExclamation, "ERRORE"
    Exit Sub
 End If
Next
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\GDNMNL78P06G843E\Documents\RATEAZIONEPROVA.xlsm"
' rest of the code
```

Hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no problem opening a workbook from a change event, so there's something else going on here.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. The problem is that indeed: can't find what's wrong with it as it seems there's no bugs,

Comment: So you're not seeing any error messages at all?  Does that `Workbooks.Open` line definitely run?  Note you might think about revising your event code so it's a little more robust - right now it wouldn't handle a multi-cell change very well.

Comment: Tim there's no error at all or that I can see. If I put a msgbox prior and after the Workbooks.open, they are shown but the workbook stay closed: it seems that the line is simply left out. And as I wrote, the same code put in an indipendent module, works great. I'm freaking out!

Comment: Update: I've tried two lines, a workbooks.add and then a cell value input in the worksheet I'm working with. The result has been that any workbook has been added but the cell has been changed. It seems that no different workbook ops can be run.

Comment: Can you share a workbook which shows the problem (minimum code to reproduce the issue)?  I'm not able to see that problem, so maybe something specific about your setup...

Comment: Ok I'll do it asap, but I have to hide parts of some lines 
different from VBA commands as the workbook is to be used for my working purposes.